# find values and erase from vector

Tags: c++, vector

Hello suppose that there is vector with 5 elements

```
vector<int> V;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
v.push_back(i);
}
```

Now how can I use find if and erase to erase values bigger than 2 from the vector ?
Would you please suggest a sample code I prepared sth but I am not sure about that.
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove from vector based on predicate (condition):

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::remove_if(      // it shifts, doesn't 
                                v.begin(), v.end(),  // reduces the physical size
                                [](int i){ return i > 2; } ));
```

and erase unneeded values:

```
v.erase( it, v.end()); // this is needed as remove_if doesn't erase
                       // elements that don't meet condition (are not to be
                       // removed), it simply moves those that don't meet 
                       // condition to the begin.
                       // now we reduce the physical size
```

### Why remove_if is followed by erase

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the
>   elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to
>   be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the
>   elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the
>   container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the
>   new logical end and the physical end of the range are still
>   dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values
>   (as per MoveAssignable post-condition). A call to remove is typically
>   followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the
>   unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to
>   match its new logical size.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

### Example

```
// Let's imagine your vector is

v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      ^              ^
      begin          end

// copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
will print: 12345

after remove_if vector becomes:

v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      ^     ^        ^
      begin it       end
// copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout)); 
// will still print a vector of size 5: 12345
// but 

// copy( v.begin(), it, ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
will print: 12

after v.erase( it, v.end()); vector becomes:
v = { 1, 2};
      ^     ^
      begin end
// copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
will print: 12
```

[compiled example](http://ideone.com/hw1W1w)

---

C++03:

```
bool f(int i) { return i > 2; }
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), f); // shifts
v.erase( it, v.end());                               // reduces the physical size
```

Comment: :perfect answer THANKS , sorry i am asking this question, since i am a beginner. i was wondering to know how the last proposed code works?

Comment: a pointer to the function, here to f, is passed to [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). This algorithm then evaluates the f(i) to check if condition is met or not and adjusts a vector accordingly - you can take a look at simplified pseudo-version of the algorithm in the link provided

Comment: All solutions work perfectly, but i still have problem with the last one i prepared a code as below and i faced with error (there is an unmatched "{" in the code)!!!!!!!
`int main()
{
 vector<int> v;

 v.push_back(1);
 v.push_back(2);
 v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(5);

 vector<int>::iterator it;
bool f(int i) {return i > 2;}
it = std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), f);  // shift
v.erase( it, v.end()); 
}`

Comment: you can take a look at this: http://ideone.com/hw1W1w

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [*erase-remove idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and a suitable functor. For example

```
V.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(V), std::end(V),
                       [](int i){ return i > 2; } ), 
                       std::end(V) );
```

If you're stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler, then

```
bool func(int i) { return i > 2; }

V.erase(std::remove_if(V.begin(), V.end(), func), V.end());
```

Comment: This really looks nice. C++11 makes things elegant.

Comment: Why you surround it with the `V.erase()`?

Comment: to erase unneeded values that remove_if left behind

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution without using `std::remove_if` just using the `erase` method and iterators.

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
IntVector v;
// fill
for (IntVector::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end();) {
    if (*it > 2) {
        it = v.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you were not supposed to modify the iterator variable inside the loop.

Comment: @Marichyasana You can do it, if you do it right. The `erase` method returns a new valid iterator after removing the element from the vector. Note that you must not `++it` in this case. It's the reason why I do it in the `else` case and not in the `for` part.